# Basic recursion with bacteria

Tags: java, recursion

Just starting to learn recursion and I am confused on this bacteria problem. Basically, I must create a method that multiplies the bacteria over a certain amount of hours. The pattern/ equation for this is `bacteriaLastHour + bacteriaLastHour * 2`. As an example, after one hour there will be 10 + 10 * 2 = 30 bacteria, and after 2 hours there will be 30 + 30 * 2 = 90 bacteria.

Here is my code:

```
public static int numBacteriaAlive(int hour)
{
    int bacteriaLastHour = 10;
    int total = 0;
    // Write a base case
    if(hour == 0){
        return 10;
    }

    // Write a recursive call
    total += (bacteriaLastHour * 2) + numBacteriaAlive(hour-1);
    bacteriaLastHour *= 3;
    return total;
}
```

For hours 1 & 2, the method works perfectly, returning 10 & 30. Yet for the other hours, the variable bacteriaLastHour doesn't change and therefore the number it return is off. My code returns 50 for 2hours (should be 90), 70 for 3hours (should be 270), etc. Any advice helps, thank you!

Edit: Cannot change parameter values

Comment: Every time your function is called, bacteriaLastHour is set to 10.  The local variable's value doesn't survive a recursive call.  You want to make it a parameter to the function itself so that its value is passed in from the previous call to the function.  (For the initial call, you would pass in a starting value of 10.)  Since it's a problem, I'll let you work out the actual approach, as this is important to learn.  Good luck.

Comment: just for curiosity, shouldn't be 270 for 3 hours? 90 + 90*2 ?

Comment: Oops forgot to mention I can't change parameters values, I am only allowed to use the hour parameter

Comment: @HenriqueForlani You're right, my mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a lot simpler than you're imagining:

```
public static int numBacteriaAlive(int hour) {
    if (hour == 0) {  // base case
      return 10;
    }

    int bacteriaLastHour = numBacteriaAlive(hour-1);  // recursive case
    return bacteriaLastHour*3;
}
```

Note: `bacteriaLastHour + 2*bacteriaLastHour` is the same as `bacteriaLastHour*3`

Once you've written the base case (for `hour==0`) then you must trust that `numBacteriaAlive(hour-1)` will return the correct value. Once you know that, returning the answer for the current hour value is easy.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I'm still having trouble visualizing what the `bacteriaLastHour*3;` is doing. If I were to code trace this, how would I?

Comment: @YeeHaw123 It's doing exactly the same calculation you did in your example for hour 1.  10 bacteria from the previous hour plus 2*10 new bacteria.  Replace 10 w/ X, and you see that (X + 2X) == 3X.  In other words, the result at the end of any given hour past the first is the previous hour's result tripled.

Comment: @YeeHaw123 No problem.  You can also eliminate the temporary local variable by changing the last two statements to a simple `return 3 * numBacteriaAlive(hour-1);`

Comment: I left the local var in there for better readability and to make it easier to understand what was going on. But removing it like @pjs mentioned is totally fine too.